# Month is not printed from a date - Java DateFormat

Tags: java, date, calendar, date-format

How to get month from a date in java :

```
        DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yy");
        Date date1 = inputDF.parse("9/30/11");

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date1);

        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        System.out.println(month+" - "+day+" - "+year);
```

This code return day and year but not month.

output :

```
0 - 30 - 2011
```

Comment: FYI: These troublesome old date-time classes seen in the Question are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. `ZonedDateTime.now().getMonthValue()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because your format is incorrect: you need `"MM/dd/yy"` for the month, because `"mm"` is for minutes:

```
DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
Date date1 = inputDF.parse("9/30/11");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date1);

int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

System.out.println(month+" - "+day+" - "+year);
```

Prints `8 - 30 - 2011` (because months are zero-based; [demo](http://ideone.com/bPi3gH))

Answer (score 5):

First, you used `mm` in your date format, [which is "minutes" according to the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).  You set the minutes to `9`, not the month.  It looks like the month defaults to 0 (January).

Use `MM` (capital 'M's) to parse the month.  Then, you will see `8`, because [in `Calendar` months start with 0, not 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH).  Add `1` to get back the desired `9`.

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is
>   JANUARY which is 0

```
// MM is month, mm is minutes
DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```

and later

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // To shift range from 0-11 to 1-12
```

Answer (score 3):

If you read the [`SimpleDateFormat` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), you'll notice that `mm` is for minutes. You need `MM` for month.

```
DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```

Otherwise the format doesn't read a `month` field and assumes a value of `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Month format should be `MM` instead of `mm`

```
 DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
```

Answer (score 1):

Time for someone to provide the modern answer. The other answers were good answers when the question was asked in 2013 and are still correct. Today there is no reason why you should struggle with the old, outdated and simultaneously notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, is so much nicer to work with:

```
    DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy");
    LocalDate date1 = LocalDate.parse("9/30/11", inputFormatter);
    System.out.println(date1);
```

This prints

```
2011-09-30
```

The `LocalDate` class represents a date without time-of-day, exactly what you need, it matches your requirement much more precisely than the old classes `Date` and `Calendar`.

The format pattern strings used with `DateTimeFormatter` resemble those from `SimpleDateFormat`, there are a few differences. You may use uppercase `MM` to require two-digit month (like 09 for September) or a single `M` to allow the month to be written with one or two digits. Similarly `dd` or `d` for day of month. `yy` denotes two-digit year and is interpreted with base 2000, that is, from 2000 to 2099 inclusive (wouldn’t work for my birthday).

**Link**: [Oracle tutorial Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using `MM` instead of `mm`:-

```
    DateFormat inputDF  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    Date date1 = inputDF.parse("9/30/11");

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date1);

    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    System.out.println(month+" - "+day+" - "+year);
```

The month printed will be 8 as index starts from 0

or try with:-

```
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Comment: The month printed will be 8, because the range for the month is 0-11, not 1-12.

Comment: @rgettman:- Added that in my answer. I thought OP must be aware of that!!

Answer (score 0):

`mm`is for minutes, use `MM` while specifying format.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date1);

int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);// returns month value index starts from 0
```