# iterate through string and assign values to int variable

Tags: java, string, date

hello I have a string like

```
String date="2014-5-20"
```

I want to assign the values

```
int year = 2014
int month = 5
int day = 20
```

How can I do it???

Comment: possible duplicate of [get month from a date - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036033/get-month-from-a-date-java)

Comment: Is that string actuakly a date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tokenize using `string.split("delimiter")`, then assign as needed! The split method breaks a string into tokens based on the delimiter that you give it.

```
String s = "2014-5-20"
String[] tokens = s.split("-");
int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0];)
int month = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
int day = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
```

You'll need to make sure that you only pass in strings that are in the valid format of number + "-" + number + "-" + number