# Calendar Class "Normal" Date issue

Tags: java, calendar

I am working on a program that will be a basic function for were a user can check something out and the program will calculate a due date which for the sake of simplicity, will be seven days later.
This function is used in other classes and today has been defined as such in the class that uses it

`today=Calendar.getInstance();`

I am using the Calendar class to do this.
At first I tried this

```
  public Calendar getReturnDate()
  {
   Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
   dueDate.set(today.MONTH, today.get(today.MONTH));
   dueDate.set(today.YEAR, today.get(today.YEAR));
   dueDate.add(today.DATE,today.get(today.DATE + 7));

   return dueDate;
}
```

This gave me a result in which everything was printed down to the millisecond.

So I researched the Calendar class and discovered that a `.add` method would do the job... or so I thought. Below is the code

```
    public Calendar getReturnDate()
{
   Calendar dueDate = Calendar.getInstance();
   dueDate.set(today.MONTH, today.get(today.MONTH));
   dueDate.set(today.YEAR, today.get(today.YEAR));
   dueDate.add(today.DATE,7);

   return dueDate;
}
```

When the function is called in the below code, the print that follows occurs.

```
    public String toString()
 {
     //Prints them out
     String str = "The specs of the book are: ";
     str+= "\n\t Title: " + title;
     str+= "\n\t Author: " + year;
     str += "\n\t checkout date: " + (getReturnDate().MONTH+1) + "/" + getReturnDate().DATE;
     return str;
 }
```

The result:

```
 Title: ABC
 Author: Suzie Smith
 checkout date: java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1428600973310,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="America/New_York",offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=235,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=America/New_York,offset=-18000000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=3,WEEK_OF_YEAR=15,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=9,DAY_OF_YEAR=99,DAY_OF_WEEK=5,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=1,HOUR_OF_DAY=13,MINUTE=36,SECOND=13,MILLISECOND=310,ZONE_OFFSET=-18000000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

As you can see this is not operating correctly. I would like for it to print out month/year when I call this method in the above code.

Does anybody know how to do this or why mine is not working?

Sources: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html

Comment: "As you can see this is not operating correctly." No, we can't really tell that. Are you mostly just annoyed by the string representation? If so, use `SimpleDateFormat`. If that's *not* the problem, please describe the actual problem more clearly. I'd also advise using `java.time` if you're using Java 8, or Joda Time otherwise. Both are better than `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: So is your question how to set hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to 0? Or are you asking if there's a way to use a Date / Calendar object that just doesn't even have these fields?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I will edit my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [get month from a date - java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036033/get-month-from-a-date-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String toString() {
    Calendar returnDate = getReturnDate();
    // Prints them out
    String str = "The specs of the book are: ";
    str += "\n\t Title: " + title;
    str += "\n\t Author: " + year;
    str += "\n\t checkout date: " + (returnDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + returnDate.get(Calendar.DATE);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I do not want it to print all of that stuff that is not needed, I simply want it to print out the month/year. Please look at my question edit.

Comment: It's "month/day" or "month/year" ? Just change in my answer "returnDate.get(Calendar.DATE)" for "returnDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)".